# When I say "comment out", does it mean to uncomment something or comment it?

Tags: meaning, programming

When I say I commented out a line written in a programming language, does that mean I uncommented that line or that I made it a comment?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

To *comment out* is to render a block of code inert by turning it into a comment.

In C# code for example, commenting out code is done by putting `//` at the start of a line, or surrounding the code with `/*` and `*/`. Here the line inside the loop is commented out:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  //Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

To *uncomment* something means to remove the characters that makes it a comment. The expression only makes sense if the comment contains something that would work as code, usually something that was commented out earlier. To uncomment a regular comment would just cause a syntax error.

Answer (score 41):

"Comment out" means to use comment syntax to remove something from the parsed code. "Uncomment" is the reverse operation. They are both the correct expression for their respective referents.

Comment: so it means something like "Remove out this line by commenting it" ?

Comment: @Genesis, no its meaning is as given above. It doesn't just apply to single line comments.

Comment: @Genesis: To clarify, as I understand it, to *comment out* means to leave the unwanted code unchanged, but insert *before it* (and *after*, for multi-line comments) the relevant character sequence that makes the compiler ignore that code when compiling. In C++ that's a double-slash before it on a single-line, or slash/asterisk before and asterisk/slash after where multiple lines are being commented out.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: A multiline comment does not necessarily (or even commonly) operate solely by inserting the comment token before and after the line. It is just as common to edit the line itself.

Comment: I don't understand what that means. Are you just saying that as an alternative to enclosing the entire unwanted section in "begin/end comment" delimiters, you can prefix each line with the sequence that means "the rest of this line is a comment". The important point is that the unwanted code itself remains unchanged - it's just that the compiler/interpreter is directed to ignore it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Your comment says that a multiline comment operates by placing the commment token before the line affected and after it. In fact, in most languages (including your example, C++), the token (or rather tokens) may be placed on the line affected, and when that occurs it is still "commenting out".

Comment: I never mentioned "the line" anywhere when referring to what was to be commented out. I called it "the unwanted code", which could be anything from part of a line to a substantial section of code.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's awkward - I misread your comment.

Comment: No worries. I think yours is the best answer anyway, but when OP paraphrased it back as "remove out this line" I thought he might not have understood the answer fully. So it seemed important to clarify that the actual text of the code being "commented out" remains unchanged - you just mark it so it's ignored.

Comment: Not sure anyone has explicitly said this yet, it may help the OP to   internalise things... The way I've always understood it is that the "out" and "in" relate to the *compilation*. You are adding/removing code from the build. "Commenting out" is taking a piece of code *out of the build*.

Answer (score 14):

As reported by the NOAD, the meaning of *comment out* is *(computing) turn part of a program into a comment so that the computer ignores it when running the program.*

> You could try commenting out that line.

The definition provided by [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/comment+out) is the following one:

> To surround a section of code with comment delimiters or to prefix every line in the section with a comment marker. This prevents it from being compiled or interpreted.

The [PC Magazine Enciclopedia](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia_term/0,2542,t=comment+out&i=40054,00.asp) defines *comment out* using the following words:

> To disable lines of code in a program by surrounding them with comment-start and comment-stop characters.

[Answers.com](http://www.answers.com/topic/comment-out) defines *comment out* as *(computer science) To render a statement in a computer program inactive by making it a comment.*

*Comment out* doesn't mean removing a comment.

Answer (score 6):

For me when you comment it is to clarify something that will make it easier for the user to understand like in c++(although a simple example and should not be used like this):

```
int n = 0;
//add 4 to variable n and then output it
n += 4;
cout << n;
```

But shall someone say comment out I think of the coder commenting out a line or section of code to see what happens with program execution. Such as this:

First code:

```
int n = 0;
n += 4;
cout << n;
```

And then commenting out a line to see what will happen with the program:

```
int n = 0;
//n += 4;
cout << n;
```

The first code will output 4 but when I comment out the second line it will output 0
I simply use this so that I don't have to delete code and then rewrite it because twe

Answer (score 5):

The idea is "remove by commenting/turning into a comment". Note that "out" is used to mean remove in a number of phrasal verbs: "dig out", "force out", "smoke out" etc-- and indeed, on more or less the same analogy "wipe out".

As the opposite, you can "uncomment" a line/section, or you "comment it back in". The latter is slightly odd, because logically you are *uncommenting* so that the code to be put back in. But hey, language doesn't always use the same logic as mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

```
//That is a function for calculating 2 intgers and display the result. - this is a comment
int add(int a, int b)
{  
    return a+b;
    print(a+b);
}
```

Now, you think the "print(a+b)" is useless, you don't want it anymore, but you want to remain it at here in case whenever you want to reuse it. You don't have to delete this line, you can just comment out it like that,

```
int add(int a, int b)
{  
    return a+b;
    //print(a+b);
}
```